# Add and remove itself from container

Tags: c++, containers, c++14

I have a class `Drawable` and a class `DrawableManager`. The `DrawableManager` should have a container of pointers to `Drawable`s, where it can look up the properties of the `Drawable` objects and draw them appropriately.

Now I want that a `Drawable` object will add itself to the `DrawableManager` on creation and remove itself on deleting. Is something like that possible? If it is, is it okay to do it or is there a better way?

The way I have it now is that I have `shared_ptr`s to the `Drawable` objects and `DrawableManager` has a `vector` of `weak_ptr`s to those objects, and I manually add the objects to the manager. I want this process automated though.

Comment: you could add/remove them on Drawable constructor/destructor

Comment: @Iosif Murariu: That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How about a custom deleter ? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059647/how-to-get-rid-of-weak-ptrs-in-a-container/19066388#19066388) to an [other similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059647/how-to-get-rid-of-weak-ptrs-in-a-container/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can pass a `DrawableManager*` to the `Drawable` constructor, which adds itself and then removes itself in the destructor. Note that at these times, its dynamic type will be `Drawable` instead of whatever the derived type is, so be careful not to call virtual methods as an immediate result of the addition.

However, I suggest that you not do this. It's often useful to separate existence from membership, to have a `Drawable` which is *not* part of a "DrawableManger" (and incidentally, see http://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/ about that). "Automating" the process removes that flexibility, for essentially no usability win.

Comment: I already pass ´DrawableManager &` to the constructor, so I can easily add it. What I was wondering about is how it can delete itself from the manager in the destructor.

Comment: But yes, I will think about seperating existance of membership, thanks.

Comment: @gartenriese To delete it, just hold a pointer to the `DrawableManager` in the `Drawable`. You could alternatively use an intrusive container, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I think I will just seperate it, it's simpler and probably better. :-)